# What happens if a condition is missed in the definition of a subdigraph?

Tags: graph-theory

> Recall that $H = (V', A')$ is a subdigraph of $D = (V,A)$ iff
>   a. $V' \subseteq V$
>   b. $A' \subseteq A$
>   c. If $vw \in A'$ then $\{v, w\} \subseteq V'$
>
> Describe what can go wrong if condition c is not included in the definition.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4klDR.png).)

I would be happy if anybody please help me in this case I am stuck here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think condition $c$ says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well why not pick a simple graph and see what would happen with your own eyes?

Take the following graph for example:[image]

You have $V=\{0,1,2\}$ and $A=\{01,12,20\}$.

Take $V'$ and $A'$ such that a. and b. are satisfied, but not c. For example: $V'=\{0,1\}$ and $A'=\{12\}$.

Try to draw the digraph $H'=(V',A')$ and you'll see what goes wrong.

Comment: Yes..got it..thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped. Since that's the case, it'd be nice to [mark the answer as accepted](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) by checking the green mark.